# Как лучше написать

Tags: предлоги

Как лучше написать - по вашей задумке или согласно вашей задумке?

Comment: без разницы, а по-хорошему написать лучше где?

Comment: Стиль разный. Предлог "согласно"  —  это книжный стиль, в разговорной речи применять нежелательно.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от смысла, но я бы предпочел **первый** вариант. "По задумке" более универсально, нежели "согласно задумке", которое больше подразумевает какое-то дальнейшее разъяснение или, к примеру, план.
Например:

1. Мы приготовили им *десерт* по вашей задумке.
2. Согласно вашей задумке, здесь необходимо возвести фундамент.